# como poner la url de una api dentro de mi aplicacion flutter?

Tags: flutter

Trabajo con esta api https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime lo que no se es como mostrarla dentro de mi app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tal cual como aparece en la api ("url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJVyIXeUznY",)
al principio intente mostrarlo dentro de un text widget, luego me di cuenta que no tenia sentido.

```
   Text(
    widget.recibirdatos.urlyoutube ?? 'no hay url',
           style: const TextStyle(
           fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
Text),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que intentas hacer es re-dirigir al usuario al link que está en la api, podrías ayudarte del paquete [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher), una vez lo tengas instalado en las dependencias al `Widget Text` que usas actualmente lo podrías encerrar en un `InkWell` o `GestureDetector`. Te quedaría algo así:

```
  InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
         if( widget.recibirdatos.urlyoutube != null &&  widget.recibirdatos.urlyoutube.isNotEmpty){

            final url = "widget.recibirdatos.urlyoutube";

            if(await canLaunch(url)){
                  await launch(url);
            }
          }
        },
      child: Text(
         widget.recibirdatos.urlyoutube ?? 'no hay url',
         style: const TextStyle(
         fontSize: 20, color: widget.recibirdatos.urlyoutube.isNotEmpty ?Colors.blue : Colors.black,
        ),
      Text,
       ),
     )
```

Hay otra forma en donde podrías llamar a un `webView` para reproducir el video dentro de la aplicación, pero creo que eso no es lo que buscas.

Comment: mi amigo te agradezco muchisimo pero no funciono. tuve que hacer algunos cambios y habian algunas cositas deprecadas. bendiciones

Comment: sin embargo me diste el inicio entonces la verdad si lo resuelve.